# ClientError: An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation (reached max retries: 4) Rate exceeded

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am getting an error in Glue job as below. However the error is not consistent. It appears randomly

> "ClientError: An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the
>   PutLogEvents operation (reached max retries: 4) Rate exceeded".

However when I see the times in the cloudwatch logs (timestamp & ingestionTime), they show more than 5 entries in the logstream.

I need to know how can I see the timestamp for when putlogevents was called?

Amazon documentation puts limits on **PutLogEvents** - 5 requests per second per log stream. Additional requests are throttled. This quota can't be changed.

Thank you! any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?